# Hiding command window in vb.net when running processes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, command-prompt

If I have this code

```
    ' Send file to Unix server via pscp
    Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C C:\pscp.exe -pw " & PASSWORD & " " & physicalFolder & "\" & UNIXSCRIPTNAME & " " & unixLogin
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Proc.Start()
    ' Allows script to execute sequentially instead of simultaneously
    Proc.WaitForExit()
```

What can I do to make the command window NOT appear when this is executed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by setting CreateNoWindow to true, This may help [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx#Y0)

```
Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true
```

Answer (score 3):

`CreateNoWindow = True`  did not work for me, Below work perfectly :

```
Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
```