# SQL Installation command from vb.net code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using following command through a batch file to install my required instance of SQL server.  Problem is, when it runs, statement is shown on screen and .bat file is open for view.
How can I run this statement through my vb.net application?

start /wait SQLEXPR32and64.EXE /qb username="MyName" companyname="COName" addlocal=ALL disablenetworkprotocols="2" instancename="ERPTesting" SECURITYMODE="SQL" SAPWD="abc123"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull that off using the accepted solution to this question: [Hiding command window in vb.net when running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781600/hiding-command-window-in-vb-net-when-running-processes)